# Why does ($false || $true) evaluate to False in Powershell 7+?

Tags: powershell, boolean-expression, powershell-7.0, logical-or, powershell-7.2

In Powershell 7.2 `Write-Output ($false || $true)` will output `False`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's not "logical OR", that would be `-or` or `-bor`. It is doing "if the first command failed, run the second one".

Referencing the variable `$false` doesn't fail, so referencing the variable `$true` isn't executed.

For comparison, try `asdfg || $true`, if the command is not found, you get an error and then `$true`.

Comment: Specifically, `||` is a [pipeline chain operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators).

Comment: Conversely, 'if' statements don't check the exit codes of commands.